# oracle-java7-installer returning error code

Tags: java, ubuntu, installation, java-7

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.3

I know this problem has been posted 1000 times and I have tried all of the fixes I can find:

1)update packages and reinstall

2)remove ppa:webupd8team/java, update, add ppa again, update

3)completely remove java and reinstall

4)Even tried apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop

5) dpkg -l | grep oracle-java7-installer returns:

```
iF  oracle-java7-installer                     7u80+7u60arm-0~webupd8~1                    
all          Oracle Java(TM) Development Kit (JDK) 7
```

6)sudo dpkg --configure -a gives:

```
Setting up oracle-java7-installer (7u80+7u60arm-0~webupd8~1) ...
Downloading Oracle Java 7...
--2018-01-22 17:47:12--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java    /jdk/7u80-
b15/jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 23.48.156.77
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.48.156.77|:80... >connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u80-b15/jdk-7u80-
linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
--2018-01-22 17:47:12--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u80-
b15/jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 23.39.16.136, >    2600:1409:a:39e::2d3e, 2600:1409:a:39c::2d3e
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|23.39.16.136|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u80-b15/jdk-7u80-
linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1516668553_f87d2b9ceb97d85524ebdf8bb77df401 >    [following]
--2018-01-22 17:47:13--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u80-
b15/jdk-7u80-linux-
x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1516668553_f87d2b9ceb97d85524ebdf8bb77df401
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.48.156.77|:80... >connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2018-01-22 17:47:14 ERROR 404: Not Found.

download failed
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
```

Every time I try to install anything, I get

```
Errors were encountered while processing:

oracle-java7-installer

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Like I said, I know it's been asking a ton of times but none of those ideas have gotten me any farther. I have the synaptic package manager and it shows that the java7-installer is downloaded and installed.

Comment: Java 7 is no longer available at that location "404 Not Found". The problem is not your machine. The problem is not the network. Oracle no longer provides that download. Simple as that.

Comment: oh my god. I have literally spent days trying to figure this out because at first I couldn't even use netbeans and it said that was the issue. I guess through all my trial and error I did fix it. I feel like an absolute idiot right now. Is there anyway to get that error to stop showing up then? I can't delete the source package because of the other files in it correct?

Comment: What source package? You only showed `oracle-java7-installer`; java7 isn't available.

Comment: all I want is for that error to stop popping up... I don't know how to make it stop popping up every time I run sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove oracle-java7-installer`

Comment: haha wow thank you. I am pretty sure last time I tried that it gave me the same error which is what made me so mad...